# Use ptrdiff_t or size_t for indexing

Tags: c, indexing, size-t

I got into the habit of declaring `for` loop indices with `size_t` instead of `int`. That however already bit me multiple times when I was iterating an array backwards, i.e. checking for the index to be greater or equal to zero:

```
for (size_t i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // ...
}
```

When the body has been run for `i == 0`, it gets decremented and wraps around, to `SIZE_T_MAX` probably. That makes the break condition a tautology. There might be some clever bit manipulations to check for possible underflows, but wouldn't it be simpler to use `ptrdiff_t` instead?

What is the proper idiomatic C way to solve this? `size_t` plus bit twiddling or `ptrdiff_t` and feeling uncomfortable about semantics?

Comment: @haccks Then, on several common platforms, you're restricted to array sizes which are quite a lot smaller than the array sizes that can reasonably be supported by the amount of physical memory. Worse, the compiler will optimize based on `int` overflow being undefined (giving quite strange behavior when it does overflow), and since it requires rather extreme inputs any problem related to this will be hard to find and reproduce.

Comment: My GCC 4.7 doesn't appear to notice the tautology (edit: with `-Wextra` it does), but my Clang 3.2 warns about it at `-Wall`. So I guess "enable warnings" is another solution?

Comment: Might be, I was just wondering if I'm 'doing it the right way'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A backwards loop should look like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    arr[n - i - 1] = foo();
}
```

The `n - i - 1` is the "reverse iterator" corresponding to `i`, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a safer way to write your downward loop:

- it works with both signed or unsigned index types,
- it uses the array length unmodified just once. You could also write `i = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)` if `arr` is defined as an array.
- `i` takes all valid index values in decreasing order.

```
for (size_t i = n; i-- > 0;) {
    arr[i] = compute_value(i);
}
```

---

<sub>One could write `i --> 0` as an eye catcher idiom, but some experts seem to disagree on this alternative.</sub>

Comment: I disagree that this is idiomatic, it is just obscure. The version posted by Kerrek is close to idiomatic, except it should be `i<n`.

Comment: "Being funny" in your source isn't.

Comment: @Lundin: if you do not like `i --> 0`, you can write `i-- > 0`. It is a matter of personal choice.  I have been using this idiom for a while and it has proven quite effective.

Comment: Or you can use the [i slides down to zero operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8909176/584518)...

Comment: @Lundin: which is by far the most upvoted question with the [c] tag and the tenth most upvoted question of all time on stack overflow :)

Comment: People like seeing posts about weird funny crap, that's why. Out of the top 10 most up-voted questions, 3 are about obfuscation, including the famous `!ErrorHasOccured() ??!??! HandleError();`.  If funny cat pictures were on topic, those would have even more votes...

Comment: Well, disregarding the aesthetics of whitespace which has now been fixed in the answer, this code will work and is perhaps less confusing and easier to get right than writing `n - i - 1` everywhere (or even just once). The only drawback is that it will occupy one more register for the back jump: https://godbolt.org/z/h6b73sfT6

On the other hand, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23971533/388010 will likewise need another register to store `n - i - 1`, just not between loop iterations (which presumably makes it easier to optimise).

Comment: Perhaps interestingly, clang is able to optimise this program to use `jb`, which is the C equivalent of `i < (size_t) -1` if that wasn't UB in C. But it isn't UB in x86_64, hence this optimisation is sound! Very nice. So the above piece of code generates optimal code there: https://godbolt.org/z/4Wo884zrG. On the other hand, the other answer does generate optimal code, too: https://godbolt.org/z/eaW4af3bc. Bottom line: As far as efficiency is concerned, it doesn't matter.